# How to find and remove duplicate records in QC ALM?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, testcase, quality-center, hp-alm

I have 1,150 test cases in my QC ALM and in Excel spreadsheet I have 1,075 test cases. There are 75 test cases which are duplicate in QC ALM and I need to remove them so that it matches the Excel test case count of 1,075.

Is there any way to find and remove duplicate records from QC ALM?

Comment: Can't you export all tests from QC to excel? and remove duplicate using excel.

Comment: Delete the test cases from ALM; import from Excel.  Should cover the requirement.

Comment: The TC ID is always unique in QC ALM (assuming all the test cases are present under one folder).  So, your duplicated tests should be having TC IDs that are not present in your excel sheet.  In this scenario, you can export TCs from QC to an excel sheet and do a vlookup against the original excel sheet.  If the TCs are present in different folders, then there is a possibility that a single TC exist in different folders with the same ID.  In this case, the solution provided by @NarendraC is the best.

Comment: Still this Q is in active queue. Can you accept any answer if found helpful, please?

Comment: OK, will try today with your scenario. If I get any issue will let you know.

Comment: sure Bharat, All the best !

Comment: If answer helped you to resolve your query, pls accept the most helpful answer so this question will not be in Active state for long

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Export all the tests from QC to excel
- Using power of Excel you can remove duplicate test easily